# Is there any way to generate protobuf file from source code?

Tags: java, c++, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I have gone through protobuf links, and after reading all that I understood that we need to create the proto file manually to generate client and server code in the specified language. But I have a requirement where I need to generate proto file dynamically (auto-generated proto file) from c++/java/rust code. Please let me know if any possibilities are there.

Comment: what do you mean exactly? Of course you can write code that generates a protobuf file, but i guess thats not what you want. Please show some code

Comment: you've tagged protobuf-net, but that is specifically for .NET - not c++/java/rust; however, *if* you were using that (protobuf-net), the answer would be "yes, `Serializer.GetProto<T>`"